# Bash script to append dynamic file path to existing .ini file possibly using sed?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sed, find

i have a commonly named .sqlite file contained within many unique user's home folders with file structure: /home/user/unique-ip-address/folder/file.sqlite I've decided to move all of these .sqlite files to a tmpfs mount and have already done so maintaining the full directory structure, so each .sqlite file is now in: /mnt/tmpfs/home/user/unique-ip-address/folder/file.sqlite

I'm looking for a way to edit a commonly named .ini file in each users home folder with a unique file path (ex: /home/user/unique-ip-address/folder/file.ini), i figure using find and sed should do the trick but i'm not sure how as the find results need to match the user to the correct folder in /mnt/tmpfs. I would like to append the new .sqlite location used in /dev/shm to file.ini in their home folders after dir= in the file.ini. Thanks!

Comment: Is this a one-off or will you want to do this regularly ?  In other words will a hack be sufficient, or do you want something robust and reliable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe something like this should do the trick:

`find /home/*/unique-ip-address/folder/file.ini | xargs -n1 perl -pe 'BEGIN{$infile="/mnt/tmpfs/$ARGV[0]"} {s/dir=/$&$infile/}'`

That command doesn't change anything, it just prints out everything. If it looks like it does what you want, just add a -i.bak to the very end and it will make the changes in place.  The original file will be renamed to file.ini.bak.

`find /home/*/unique-ip-address/folder/file.ini | xargs -n1 perl -pe 'BEGIN{$infile="/mnt/tmpfs/$ARGV[0]"} {s/dir=/$&$infile/} -i.bak'`

Comment: Thanks for the help! This worked great with some slight modification, and it was just a hack not something that needs to be done regularly.

Comment: Oh also, i suppose the only thing to make this far better, just in case i need to run it in the future or more than once right now sed is dumping the database= line in over any existing change, so if the script gets run twice it breaks everything. Is there a way to have it check to see if database= has been set or is it easier to just remove the database= line from the .ini file every time it is run and replace it from scratch?

Comment: assuming your dir=/database= line is one line just change the s/dir=/ to s/dir=.*$/ so it captures everything to the end of the line. at least that is what i think you mean.